# Is complex exact if its Euler characteristic is zero?

Tags: homological-algebra

For a bounded complex $M$ of finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces we define its Euler characteristic as
$$
\chi=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n\dim(M_n)
$$
In particular, if complex is exact then its Euler characteristic is zero. Is the converse true?

Comment: How long have you thought about this? The euler characteristic knows *nothing* about the boundary maps!

Comment: Evidently, not for long enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider $$0\to k\stackrel 0\to k\to 0 $$

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to mention a positive result. As Martin Brandenburg pointed out, the Euler characteristic knows nothing about the boundary maps, so we might as well define the Euler characteristic of a bounded graded vector space (i.e. graded by $\mathbb Z$ with all spaces null but finitely many).

We say such a bounded graded vector space $V_.$ is:

- *potentially exact* if you can endow it with differentials that turn it into an exact complex.
- *stably potentially exact* if there is a potentially exact bounded graded vector space $V'_.$ such that $V_. \oplus V_.'$ is potentially exact.

**Theorem**: A bounded graded vector space is stably potentially exact if and only if its Euler characteristic is zero.

For a proof, see Grayson, *Algebraic K-theory via binary complexes*, lemma 5.4. It is stated and proved in greater generality there.